# Use Hints for execution of all the conditions in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, optimizer-hints

Consider a query like :

```
select * from <table_name>
where <condition1> and <condition2> and <condition3>;
```

Suppose Oracle executes the condition (any condition) and if not true, it does not execute the other conditions. So if I have other conditions that have logical error then it is not thrown. For example:

```
select count(*) from dual 
where 1=0 and 
'stack' = SUBSTR('stackoverflow','k', 3);
```

Oracle returns 0. Now remove the 1=0 condition, we get `ORA-01722: invalid number`.

I know that Oracle does the cost optimization and decides the order of condition execution. So how do I override this and make it execute all the conditions so that error is thrown instead of the misleading output? Can we use hints? I am new to the hints concept, so some example would be great.

Comment: If you know that "Oracle does the cost optimization and decides the order of condition execution" why do you still think that "Oracle executes the condition1 ..."

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ - What is your real issue?

Comment: well when I remove the 1=0 condition, I get the error but not otherwise. So that would mean that Oracle skipped execution, right?

Comment: I though my question made it clear: `make it execute all the conditions so that error is thrown`

Comment: But is doesn't mean it executes the predicates by their order. I'm opening an answer in order to give you a clear example.

Comment: Sorry, but this make no sense. If you know that you have data issue you should handled it at the source or in the code and not wait for exceptions to occur.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I edited my post, making it clear that regardless of which predicate is executed first, rest are not executed - my real issue.

Comment: what do you think Oracle should execute after this condition? where 1=0 there is no records after this clause, you are doing something wrong if you thinking that way

Comment: Are you trying to solve real problem or is it a theoretical question? What is your goal?

Comment: @MarcinWroblewski A real problem made me question this working. But either point of view, real life or theoretical is welcome here

Comment: "so that error is thrown instead of the misleading output?" ... the output is not misleading at all. No rows would be output, which is the correct result.

Comment: @DavidAldridge How is it a correct result?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that solves your "problem" whatever it is, but here's one approach. This query is more or less equivalent to yours, and raises the error.

```
SQL> with t as (
  2  select /*+ materialize */ * from   dual
  3   where  'stack' = substr('stackoverflow', 'k', 3)
  4  )
  5  select * from t where 1 = 0;
 where  'stack' = substr('stackoverflow', 'k', 3)
                                          *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

However no guarantee. `materialize` is just a hint and as such it may not be obeyed.

Comment: Thank you for the `materialize` hint pointer :) I will do some research around that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check condition one by one or simply using `OR`keyword to check only errors.

```
    select count(*) from dual 
    where 'stack' = SUBSTR('stackoverflow',1,5) and  1=0
   --  True and False return 0


    select count(*) from dual 
    where 'stack' = SUBSTR('stackoverflow','a',5) and  1=0
    --  True and False  return 0


   select count(*) from dual 
   where 'stack' = SUBSTR('stackoverflow',1,5) and  1=1
   --  True and True Return 1
```

here oracle first checks wrong condition 1=0 then its not checking another condition which also have logical error like invalid number 'a' in substr syntax.

Comment: a huge NO! nothing ensures you evaluation of predicates by their order.

Answer (score 0):

> The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than
>   your actual problem. This leads to enormous amounts of wasted time and
>   energy, both on the part of people asking for help, and on the part of
>   those providing help.

[xyproblem.info](http://xyproblem.info/)

---

FYI

There used to be an ORDERED_PREDICATES hint
[Optimizer Hints](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm#13676)

That was deprecated in 10g
[What's New in Oracle Performance?](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10752/whatsnew.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am working on 12c, so obviously that hint can not be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *

from    <table_name>

where   case 
            when    <condition1> 
            then    case
                        when    <condition2> 
                        then    case
                                    when    <condition3>
                                    then    1
                                end
                    end
        end = 1
```

Comment: I think you are doing something terribly wrong here, but here it is.

Comment: Yes, the next question would be "my performance is terrible -- how do I optimise this?"

Comment: @DavidAldridge :-)